# how to remove table padding when using CLI --convert-to parameter in LibreOffice

Tags: command-line-interface, libreoffice

I have a script which generates a HTML document, which is then converted to a .doc file using something like this:

```
libreoffice5.3 --headless --convert-to doc:"MS Word 97" input.html --outdir outputdir
```

I cannot set the padding on the table cells. They always end up with 0.5cm space at the bottom.

I have tried adding page-wide CSS such as "td{padding:0cm;}", and tried adding the CSS directly to the  elements themselves, and even tried adding "cellpadding=0" to the  element.

I remember reading somewhere that it might be possible to apply a predefined style to a document by using a template filter, but I can't seem to find an example of anyone ever doing this.

So, my question: how do I remove cell padding from tables when converting from HTML to Doc in LibreOffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it.

When converting  elements from HTML to Doc (or PDF, etc), LibreOffice sets a margin (not padding!) on the table cells. This is not intuitive in the least, as margin is supposed to be outside an element, not inside it.

To remove the space, simply add this to the HTML:

```
<style>th,td{margin:0cm}</style>
```

LibreOffice needs the "cm" part because it doesn't understand that 0 of anything at all is still 0...

Comment: Can you please tell me where did you find  that "LibreOffice sets a margin (not padding!) on the table cells."? I have similar problem, I want to have a control over page margins so I would like to know where to look at all, how to find out where LibreOffice is setting that? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I don't remember, to be honest. I probably came to that conclusion through trial and error.